# HttpListenerResponse adding a 2nd cookie makes all cookies disappear

Tags: c#, cookies

I have the following code:

```
    void WriteConnectionId(HttpListenerContext context, string id)
    {
        var cookie = context.Response.Cookies[CookieConnectionId];
        if (cookie == null)
        {
            cookie = new Cookie(CookieConnectionId, id)
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = true,
                Path = "/"
            };
            context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        else
        {
            cookie.Value = id;
        }
        //context.Response.SetCookie(new Cookie("lalala", "lololo"));
    }
```

This code stores correctly the cookie for "connection Id" in the client. In Chrome's console I can see the cookie in the list of cookies.

However, if I uncomment the last line that adds an extra cookie, then neither the session cookie or the dummy cookie make it to the client. They do not appear in Chrome's console.

**Edit: removing the "/" path on the first cookie makes the first cookie appear, though with both values from the 1st and 2nd cookie concatenated with a comma.**

Comment: Did you try changing the last line to `Context.Reponse.Cookies.Add(new Cookie("lalala","lololo"));`?

Comment: yes, same result =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue by creating the following function:

```
    void FlushCookie(HttpListenerContext context, Cookie cookie)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(cookie.Name);
        builder.Append("=");
        builder.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(cookie.Value));
        builder.Append(";");
        context.Response.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie, builder.ToString());
    }
```

This can be modified further to add cookie expiration, path, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
context.Response.AppendCookie(new Cookie("lalala", "lololo"));
```